# Using Excel to separate complex many-to-many relationships

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, pivot-table, power-query

I have a set of data in excel that follows the below format:
[Table displaying data and its attributes/relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uqSQ.png)
[Image displaying relationships between High, Medium and Low level attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqLdG.png)

I need help finding a way to display this information in:

1. A way that is **semi-interactive within the excel workbook** that the raw data sits in (think something like pivot table, using the slicer as a clickable filter)
2. **Easy/quick to update whenever a change is made to the raw data** table. (there are over 350 applications, each with their own application names and various High/Medium/Low Level attributes)

One solution that I have found (but is wildly inefficient and tedious) is manually creating a new row for each Low Level Attribute and matching it up 1 by 1 to the relevant Medium level attribute, High Level attribute and Application Name. However, this has to be done in a separate worksheet not linked to the current worksheet, and with how many Low Level attributes there are that are spread across all 360 applications, it is simply not possible in a feasible timescale. An example of this solution is below (all done manually):

[2 Tables demonstrating the manual separation solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFV32.png)

I have tried using Power Query to separate and create a new row manually using the comma as a delimiter, however it is ineffectual on Applications where there are multiple high/medium/low level attributes, as it will (incorrectly) copy the information across multiple rows.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Power Query using helper columns and a filter

See the code comments and follow the applied steps to understand the algorithm.

The code is "hard-coded" for just three levels of attributes, with the names you show.

If there should be a variable number of sub-attributes, the code could be changed to accommodate using `List.Accumulate` or `List.Generate` which would allow looping.

***Original Data***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//split the columns by delimiters into rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"High Level Attribute/s", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "High Level Attribute/s"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"Medium Level Attribute/s", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Medium Level Attribute/s"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", {{"Low Level Attribute/s", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Low Level Attribute/s"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"High Level Attribute/s", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Medium Level Attribute/s", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Low Level Attribute/s", Text.Trim, type text}}),

//Add "grouper columns"
    #"Add Med Grouper" = Table.AddColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Medium Grouper", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([#"Medium Level Attribute/s"],".",0), type text),
    #"Add Low Grouper" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Med Grouper", "Low Grouper", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([#"Low Level Attribute/s"],".",1), type text),

//Filter the table based on equality between attribute and next lower lever grouper column
    filtered = Table.SelectRows(#"Add Low Grouper", each 
            [#"High Level Attribute/s"] = [Medium Grouper]
            and [#"Medium Level Attribute/s"] = [Low Grouper]),
            
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(filtered,{"Medium Grouper", "Low Grouper"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, ended up working perfectly! I had to tweak it a bit to accept further text in the attribute columns, but your code provides a perfect skeleton solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query has a "Split Columns" feature that can be set on a delimiter (such as a comma), and then split into a separate row for each comma (with the other columns retaining the same information). That should separate out the rows for you based on each attribute, then you can create a pivot table based off the new data with the separated out rows. This means you can retain the interactivity whilst also being to update the information quickly.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work as it will end up with the wrong High/Medium/Low level attributed being linked together. 

For example, under Application Gamma, if you run the High Level Attribute comma through the split column by delimiter feature, it will not accurately spread out the Medium and Low level attributes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach using formulas (Office 365):

`=IFNA(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE("."&TEXTSPLIT(E4,,", ")&".",".",SEQUENCE(,4)),"."),B4)`

[image]

Or for multiple cells:

```
=LET(range,B4:E5,
DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,IFNA(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE("."&TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(TAKE(range,,-1),y),,", ")&".",".",SEQUENCE(,4)),"."),INDEX(TAKE(range,,1),y))))),1))
```